# Getting the index of specific element in a list after slicing in python

Tags: python, list, enumerate

Given a list of employees' scores. the employee with the highest score among the first k employees or the last k employees in the score list is selected. then removed from the list.

I want to get the real index for the selected element.

```
score=[5, 12, 15, 11, 15]
k=2
max_value = max(max(score[:k]), max(score[-k:]))
index=score.index(max_value)
print(index)
score.remove(score[index])
print(score)
```

the output is :

```
2
[5, 12, 11, 15]
```

the desired output:

```
4
[5,12,15,11]
```

The problem is index() will return the first occurrence. I know enumerate can be a solution somehow, but I am not able to apply it in my code.

Comment: But the max of the max of the sliced list is also the max of the hole list? So `max(max(score[:k]), max(score[-k:]))`  does the same as `max(score)`.  And then you could get the index of that element with `index(max(score))`.

Comment: not necessary, in some cases, the elements in the middle (not taken during slicing ) will be the max. I give this list just as an example.

Comment: Okay, I know what you mean by that now. But the rest of your question is just not clear. Please specify what you are doing there / what is your goal is.

Comment: It might be easier to find the best solution if we knew what *underlying problem is solved* by treating the list this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank for editing your question. I think I now understood what you want. Of course this can be shorten by removing some variables. I left them there to make the code more clear.

```py
score = [5, 15, 12, 15, 13, 11, 15]

k = 2

first = score[:k]
last = score[-k:]

cut = [*first, *last]
max_value = max(cut)

for i in range(len(score)):
    if (i < k or i >= len(score)-k) and score[i] == max_value:
        score.pop(i)
        break

print(score)
```

Answer (score 2):

### Seems like You want to remove the last highest value from the list

You'll need to find all indices of the max value, then just use the last index to remove the item from the list:

```
max_val_indices = [i for i, x in enumerate(score) if x == max(score)] # max_val_indices = [2, 4]
score.remove(max_val_indices) # score = [5,12,15,11]
print(max_val_indices[-1:], score) # desired output: 4 [5,12,15,11]
```

**One-liner:**

```
score.remove([i for i, x in enumerate(score) if x == max(score)][-1:]) # score = [5,12,15,11]
```